# Como redirecionar requisição quando @PreAuthorize retorna false

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Estou aprendedo sobre o `Spring MVC` e `Spring Security`.

Como faço para redirecionar a página quando a seguinte linha retornar `false`
dentro de um `@Controller` ?

```
@PostAuthorize(" hasRole('page')")
```

Se a linha acima retorna `true` não há problema e a página é exibida corretamente.

Se a linha acima retorna `false`  página é exibida! Mas todas variáveis ficam faias, Ex: exibe uma tabela somente com o cabeçalho e sem nehuma linha.

Pergunto: como fazer para que ao invés de exibir a página vazia, seja redirecionar para outra página?

Answer (score 0):

Pense se é possível fazer algo assim em seu controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/login", "/"})
    public String login(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user){
        //se usuario for true (logado), manda pra home
        if(user != null){
            return "redirect:/home";
        }
       //se usuario for vazio (falso), retorna pro login
        return "Login";
    }
```